# When to Create a New Adapter for RecyclerView - notifyDataSet() Not Working?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am currently working on creating an app which will display a grid of current movie posters to the end user. I obtain the movie data by using [TheMovieDB](https://www.themoviedb.org/documentation/api) API and the data is obtained in the app by using an ASync task. I would like to eventually be able to implement pagination in my app, where the user is shown a quasi-endless grid of movie posters.

Therefore, the way I've approached this is I've created my `Movie` model object, which will store a few pieces of data about each movie. Then, when I pull data from the API, I fill an `ArrayList`full of movie objects. However, I am unsure of how many movies will be created once I implement pagination. To be safe, I've initialized my `ArrayList` to not contain any movies. Once my ASync task completes (as in, within `onPostExecute()`), I append all of the movies to my array.

The issue that I'm now facing is that, within `onPostExecute()` of my task, I thought that `notifyDataSetChanged()` would present me with a grid of movie posters. However, that doesn't appear to be the case. I'm unsure of why, but I have to recreate the adapter with my newly-appended array in order for the posters to show up on the screen. The only reason I recreate the adapter in `onPostExecute()` is because I saw it somewhere else on the net, but didn't completely understand why it was used.

Here is the code that I am working with:

```
package com.example.android.popularmovies_stage1;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MovieSelection extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    MovieAdapter mAdapter;
    List<Movie> mMoviesList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_movie_selection);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_movie_selection);
        GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 3);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mAdapter = new MovieAdapter(mMoviesList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        new FetchMoviesTask().execute();
    }

    private class MovieAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieHolder>{
        private List<Movie> adapterMovies;

        public MovieAdapter(List<Movie> movies){
            adapterMovies = movies;
        }

        @Override
        public MovieHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType){
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.movie_list_item, viewGroup, false);

            return new MovieHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MovieHolder holder, int position){
            Movie currentMovie = adapterMovies.get(position);
            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                    .load("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/" + currentMovie.getPosterPath())
                    .into(holder.holderImageView);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount(){
            return adapterMovies.size();
        }

    }

    private class MovieHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView holderImageView;

        public MovieHolder(View movieView){
            super(movieView);
            holderImageView = (ImageView) movieView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_image_view);
        }


    }


    private class FetchMoviesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Movie>>{
        @Override
        protected List<Movie> doInBackground(Void... params){
            return new MovieFetcher().fetchMovies();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Movie> parsedMovies){
            mMoviesList = parsedMovies;
//            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  Unsure of why this is not working as I expected?
            mAdapter = new MovieAdapter(mMoviesList);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Why does the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method not work as expected? Why do I have to recreate my adapter if the `ArrayList` is initialized without any data? Of course, any assistance on this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Batter to create one method `addData` in adapter and just call that method pn `onPostExecute()`  like `mAdpater.setData(mMoviesList)` then do `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: `notifyItemRangeInserted (int positionStart, 
                int itemCount)` can also be used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing reference of ListView which Adapter holds.

```
// New reference which is causing issue, use .addAll() property of ArrayList.
mMoviesList = parsedMovies;
```

Update your code in postExecute() -

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Movie> parsedMovies){
        mMoviesList.addAll(parsedMovies);
        // Now I am sure this will work :)
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
    }
```

*Reason* - Your new `MovieFetcher().fetchMovies()` must creating new `ArrayList` inside which get return in postExecute, and if you assign that new ArrayList to a list which is passed to Adapter of your ListView then reference get changed and your Adapter will not listen to updates(notifyDataSetChanged), because your data set is not changed, only reference is changed.

Comment: Thank you! This has completely solved my issue. And your explanation make sense :D

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Movie> parsedMovies){
        mMoviesList.add(parsedMovies);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call notifyDataSetChanged() method after setting adapter to the RecyclerView not before.

like:

```
private class FetchMoviesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Movie>>{
    @Override
    protected List<Movie> doInBackground(Void... params){
        return new MovieFetcher().fetchMovies();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Movie> parsedMovies){
        mMoviesList = parsedMovies;
        mAdapter = new MovieAdapter(mMoviesList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In onPostExecute() you are adding below line

```
 mMoviesList = parsedMovies;
```

which means `mMoviesList` creating new instance, hence `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` won't work.

**Use below code**

```
private class FetchMoviesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Movie>>{
    @Override
    protected List<Movie> doInBackground(Void... params){
        return new MovieFetcher().fetchMovies();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Movie> parsedMovies){
      // mMoviesList.clear();// If you want clear existing data add this line, otherwise remove it
       if(parsedMovies != null){
           mMoviesList.addAll(parsedMovies);
       }
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  Unsure of why this is not working as I expected?
    }  //end of onPostExecute
}  //end of FetchMoviesTask
```

For your reference [check here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged())